# How to make sub domains run on ssl along with domain

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have bought a wildcard ssl certificate for my website let say www.example.com

I am using ubuntu 14.04 server on AWS hosting and using apache 2.4. My domain is booked from godaddy.

I wanted two of my folders js & css to show up as sub domains ie. `js.example.com and css.example.com`. So that on page load all the files from css and js folders load faster.

I have managed to enable settings for making `css.example.com` and `js.example.com` in apache. Also I have configured ssl certificate with my website and enabled https ie. `https://www.example.com`

Now the problem is, I am unable to setup ssl or secure vhost for my js & css sub-domains.

Now when I open my website with https://www.example.com, warnings are appearing in console for unsecured origin of js and css files. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, you can't.

Your certificate (I'm assuming) is for www.example.com; not for js.example.com, css.example.com or *anything else*.example.com.

A certificate that is for *anything*.example.com is a wildcard certificate and they cost more.

An alternative would be adding Subject Alternate Names (SAN) to your certificate to cover js.example.com and css.example.com, but you'd have to do that at the requesting stage - you can't do it retrospectively.  Chances are, there would be charge for that too.

So your options are to purchase a replacement certificate, or alternatively, move your css and js to a subdirectory on your website so that they are accessed as https://www.example.com/css and https://www.example.com/js using your current certificate.

However, if you have purchased a wildcard certificate or a certificate with SANs that cover all your various domains and are still getting errors, then the issue is likely to be with Apache.

You need to make sure that the Apache subdomain for both ccs and js are also using https.  If they use http you'll get the warnings you state.

Comment: thanks for responding so quick. I happen to have wildcard ssl certificate. Can you tell me the procedure with this certificate? I happen to have alpha and beta testing websites as well so I picked wildcard certificate to make them secure as well.